# Pandas set column on partial string match using for loop: Error indexing with vector containing NaN

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a method for assigning a column using a partial string match. I have now expanded this method to use with a list of strings by use of a for loop as per this example:

mydf:

```
         mytestdata Colourtoassign
0  blah Orange blah          FALSE
1     blah blah Red          FALSE
```

Where *Colourtoassign* is a column to be assigned on partial string match in the for loop using the list colourList:

['Black',
 'Blue',
 'Green',
 'Orange',
 'Pink',
 'Purple',
 'Red',
 'White',
 'Yellow',
 'Hot Pink']

I put this into my for loop as below:

```
for i in range(len(colourList)-1):
mydf.loc[mydf['mytestdata'].str.contains(colourList[i]), 'Colourtoassign'] = colourList[i]
```

Yielding the desired result for mydf:

```
         mytestdata Colourtoassign
0  blah Orange blah         Orange
1     blah blah Red            Red
```

However when I try and use it with my real data as per below example:

```
for i in range(len(cableList)-1):
ordersTwo.loc[ordersTwo['Variation details'].str.contains(cableList[i]), 'VariationStringLabel_FULL'] = cableList[i]
```

I get the error *ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA/NaN values*.

The relevant columns of this dataframe:

ordersTwo['Variation details']:

```
0                                                  NaN
1                                                  NaN
2    [Cable Length (metres):3M (9ft, 10in),Colour:Hot Pink]
3    [Cable Length (metres):2M (6ft, 7in),Colour:Hot Pink]
```

ordersTwo['VariationStringLabel_FULL']:

```
0    FALSE
1    FALSE
2    FALSE
3    FALSE
```

Although I don't believe it is the vector upon which indexing is occuring, I tried removing the NaN's of *ordersTwo['Variation details']* using *ordersTwo['Variation details'].fillna(0, inplace=True)* but the result is the same.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True)

where na: default NaN, fill value for missing values.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

try below code:

```
for i in range(len(cableList)-1):
    ordersTwo.loc[ordersTwo['Variation details'].str.contains(cableList[i], na=False), 'VariationStringLabel_FULL'] = cableList[i]
```